# Changing the text in an SSRS report textbox based on the toggle state of a row group

Tags: reporting-services

Apparently this should have been simple. After lots of digging, I'm yet to find anything that works. I have a row group in my SSRS report whose visibility is toggled by a textbox. What I want is to have the text **Show** in the textbox when it's collapsed, and **Hide** when it's expanded.

But I can't find any property of the group that can give me its toggle state. I have found in a few forums that it's not possible. As a workaround, I've tried the **InScope()** function ( as suggested in http://forums.asp.net/t/1601570.aspx/1). But to no avail. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in stating that SSRS does not expose the ToggleState property for use in the report.

In these types of situations, I use report parameters to control the state of the report.  For example, you could add a parameter named isGroupVisible to the report with a default value of 1 to represent visible. Set your group's visibility to that parameter, and set your text box value conditioned on the state of isGroupVisible.  Then in the text box you set your actions to be go to a report, and set the report url to be the same report with the isGroupVisible = to the opposite of what it currently is.

You can decorate your text box all you want to give the users the indication that it can be pressed to toggle the state of the report.

Draw backs to this approach is that it isn't as snappy as the ajax calls SSRS does to expand visibility--it will post back to the server on each toggle press.

Advantages to this approach include much more flexibility in controlling the state of the report.